# Need a 9 char length unique ID

Tags: distributed-computing

My application uses a 9 digit number (it can be alphanumeric also). I can start with any number and then increments it at the beginning. But my application is not a single instance application, so if I run this `exe` as another instance, it should increment the latest value and the previous instance should again increment the latest value when it needs that value. I mean at all time, the value should be latest incremented value among all the instances that I open.

This is half of the problem. The other side is, `exe`s can be run on any machine on the network and each instance should keep on incrementing (just like time never goes back) for another 2 years. My restrictions is that I can't use files to store and retrieve the latest value in common place.

How can I do that?

A 9 char/digit UNIQUE NUMBER also works for sure. The whole idea is to assign a number (String of 9 char length) to each "confidential file" and (encrypt it and whatever, which is not my job)

I tried with:

1. GUID which is unique in total 128 bits but not with last or first 9 chars
2. Tick count more than 9
3. MAC address unique only if 12 chars
4. ISBN (book numbering system)

And so on ...

Comment: Are you sure you have put right tags? This more looks to be a question on XML WEB services...

Comment: "My restrictions is that I can't use files to store and retrieve the latest value in common place." By *common place*, do you mean accessible from the whole network? Are you allowed to use the filesystem for sharing information between processes on the same machine? Also, what is the expected frequency for number assignment?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach might be to have unique number server which each instance of you application queries over the network to get unique numbers.

Comment: Agreed.  That's really the only valid approach since they only have 9 chars to work with.

Comment: I do not necessarily agree, depending on the requirements. A server like this would introduce a single point of failure in the system, which is relevant since this system seems to be up for two years non-stop. A truly distributed solution based on 3 digits from the IP address with 6 digits remaining for local uniqueness seems better to me.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to remove the distributed aspect from the problem. Like user Hugo suggested, using the last 2 or 3 bytes of the IP address should work. Your problem is now reduced to a local problem for each single machine.

Your algorithm probably needs to be able to deal with a restart, and not start handing out the same numbers after a reboot. You state that you do not have the option to use a file to store and retrieve information about this mechanism via a file system. This means that a random number generator alone would not be good enough, and you need a time-based component in your number generator as well. If you use 4 bytes containing the number of seconds elapsed since *some date* you will have more than 100 years of uniqueness in that. However, ideally the time-scale to use here depends on the expected handout-frequency of your numbers. Your problem is now reduced to a local problem for each single machine for each single second.

The final 2 or 3 bytes are then available to ensure local uniqueness for the second. Depending on your requirements and operating system, there are multiple IPC mechanisms to manage this, like pipes, sockets or shared memory. Or you could think of more creative ways. If you know the number of participating processes on a node, you could assign a sequence number to each process at startup or configuration time, and 1 of the 2 or 3 bytes is used for that. Your uniqueness problem has now become local to your process to one second only, which should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be EXACTLY 9?  UUIDs would be great if that didn't limit you.

In any case, your best shot is to generate a random number.  If all your PCs are in the same network, use the host-digits of the IP address at the begining to avoid colission.  This should be no more than 16 or 24 bits in most cases anyway, so you have 6 remaining digits.

Comment: In about 2005 Microsoft changed its GUID generation procedure from being IP/TIME based to be a pure random number.

Comment: For random numbers to be viable, they need to have a lot more than 9 digits (or even 9 printable characters).

Comment: @R.. As I said, each machine has a unique prefix, and each can check there is no collision with itself.

Comment: Checking for no collision after making a random number is still fairly expensive even local to one machine. It requires synchronization between all processes using the number.

Comment: You do realize that the accepted answer actually checks collision over the network, so the inefficiency of this is actually negligible in comparison.